# GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API fails in a release build

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-api-client

When my app is a built as a debug build I can login correctly, but when I build as a signed APK and release in Google Play the same account can't login.

Is there an extra Google API permission that I'm missing?

> mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
>                   .enableAutoManage(this, this )
>                   .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
>                   .build();
>
> ...
>
> GoogleSignInResult result = 
>   Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data); if
>   (!result.isSuccess()) { .. }

Comment: As I understand, you have provided the debug SHA1 in the Google developer console, then you signed the apk and the SHA1 changed.

Comment: Yup that was it. I added the SHA1 from the release certificate to the apps SHA certificate fingerprints in the firebase console, linked the firebase account to the google play account, then I could login. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have provided the debug SHA1 in the Google developer console, then you signed the apk and the SHA1 changed.

Comment: Thank you - that was the problem.